# Pandas data frame to existing Excel template with formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I'm currently doing an ETL process and am stuck with this data frame to excel issue. (Removed image tag due to lack of reputation)

I have an excel file template which looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajaaX.png

Running a dataframe with values inside, I want to open up that template,(there will be future data in it) and dump the dataframe inside so ideally it'll look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynkBC.png

However, when i run my code, i kept getting this output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecKmK.png

The table formatting stops at cell C2
is there anyway to push the data INTO the table formatting template(appending values)?

I have tried using openpyxl and pandas in-built excel code `to_excel` but it all did not work out. I kept getting the same error whereby the table format stops at the 2nd row.

I have also tried adding/removing the header in my data frame to match with the header in the excel file but there were no difference.

My current code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
import os,sys
from openpyxl import load_workbook

d = {'this': [1, 2, 3], 'is': [4, 5, 6], 'test': [7, 8, 9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
file_descr = 'test.xlsx'

def write_data(self, file_descr):
    """
    Use dataframe to_excel to write into file_descr (filename) - open first if file exists.
    """
    if os.path.isfile(file_descr):
        book = load_workbook(file_descr)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_descr, engine='openpyxl')
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header= True,
                              float_format='%.2f')

        ## Using xlswriter as an engine
        # writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_descr,engine = 'xlsxwriter')
        # df.to_excel(writer,index=False,sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
        # workbook = writer.book

        writer.save()
    else:
        self.data_df.to_excel(file_descr, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False,
                              float_format='%.2f')

write_data(df,file_descr)
```

Comment: You'll need to adjust the table definition manually.